# quotes inside array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var i=blue;

var mycars = new Array();

mycars[0] = "'Sa'+i+'b'";


for (i=0;i<mycars.length;i++)
{
document.write(mycars[i] + "<br />");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i cant display mycars[0] element.
How do i display mycars[0] element?

This is the script im trying to work with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
document.getElementById("rednoize").innerHTML="Checking..";
document.getElementById("hashcracking").innerHTML="Checking..";
var url=document.getElementById('ul').value;

if(url)
{
var md5_sites = new Array();
var results = new Array();
var md5_sites[0]= 'http://md5.rednoize.com/?p&s=md5&q='+ url +'&_=' ;
var md5_sites[1]= 'http://www.md5.hashcracking.com/search.php?md5='+ url ;

//rest of script
```

In firebug i get error as: `missing ; before statement` line 38

Comment: What are you trying to do with `"'Sa'+i+'b'"`? Maybe you just want `'Sa'+i+'b'`.

Comment: What is the expected output? What would other items in `mycars` might look like?

Comment: i inlcuded the original script i was working with.Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be var i = "blue" and not blue unless blue is a global var.
Also, it should be

mycars[0] = 'Sa'+i+'b';

To get Sablueb as output.

Answer (score 1):

Use different logic. For example, something like this should work fine:

```
mycars[0] = "Sa{0}b";
for (i=0;i<mycars.length;i++) {
   document.write(mycars[i].replace("{0}", i) + "<br />");
}
```

This "template" logic is pretty generic, and better than the alternative which is `eval`.

Comment: Ohh... Now I understand what the OP is trying to do. `var i = 'blue';`, `mycars[0] = "'Sa'" + i + "'b'";` (`i` is used twice here, so you might be right as well)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var i=blue;
```

… attempts to set the value of `i` to be the same as the value of `blue`, but `blue` hasn't been defined so you get an Uncaught ReferenceError and the script dies.

Comment: It's not relevant to the problem, see what he's trying to do..

Comment: i inlcuded the original script i was working with.Thanks for response.